# check matches and match type for strings with multiple words against array of words

Tags: python

I have a fixed array of words and I have a set of strings for which I want to check if it contains a match against the array of words.
I also want to determine the type of match out of the four possible:

- single word, exact match
- multiple words, one of them exact match
- single word, partial match
- multiple words, partial match

I have the checks for the first 3, but struggling to get the 4th type. Also wondering if this can be done better/more pythonic/more efficient.

```
a = ['1234','tes','1234 abc','tes abc']
b = ['1234','testing12','test']

def match_string(a, b):
    if [a for x in b if a.lower() == x.lower()]:
        match_type = 'exact - single'
    elif [a for x in b if a.lower() in x.lower()]:
        match_type = 'partial - single'
    elif [a for x in b if x.lower() in a.lower()]:
        match_type = 'exact - multiple'
    #add check for 4th type; 'partial - multiple'
    else:
        match_type = 'no match'
        
    return match_type

for string in a:
    print(match_string(string, b))
```

desired output is 'exact - single', 'partial - single','exact - multiple','partial - multiple'

Comment: `[("partial - multiple" if len(w) > 1 else "partial - single") if (w := set(i.split())).intersection(x := [k for j in w for k in b if j in k]) else ("exact - multiple" if len(w) > 1 else "exact - single") if x else "no match" for i in a]`

Comment: this gave me wrong results on the example

Comment: Yes, my bad, just switch `"partial"` and `"exact"` or invert condition. [Tio](https://tio.run/##jVLBbsIwDL33K6ycEokhATtMSPAj04RCcUcgpFVi1Fbav3dJWkZLyzb30OTZjp@fXdR0zM3qrbBNI2EDbLFcvbIZMEIXfuEKcp920O14yPzHkv1DBinzuVjeLixJDpjBRVJ63Dmy3smrGdRinYC30idXc1doRVxEJMstKFAGyjYimMpaqL5DHazR8FLAFhZDVzCLdLUGGFYyJXiBy1WTKjSyQSRqh3/nOs@7nznOCrxPEyT7/E9j1z/6eORUSEtK6qcd/d7Z89f6Pd68Jm9HNzHGXW5wp5VB2x9ol8jHqg/bjOxG@ooQxEtYb8Ah8Z/NEGKuDKF1mJLKDdch4v18F72Mx3PUP7wRwfOHaMvwKc0m@YzUiIx05@2pEcq5UES2fRdeEuLOb/2XX/3BuntwLyYcPQFjiGiabw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to initialize loop for every condition. Firstly split first string into *words* *([`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split))*. Then iterate over *words* and check if your *static list of words* contains *word*. If not iterate over *constant list of words* and check if any *constant word* contains *word*.

```py
def match_string(x, y):
    w = x.split()
    for i in w:
        if i in y:
            if len(w) > 1:
                return "exact - multiple"
            else:
                return "exact - single"
        else:
            for j in y:
                if i in j:
                    if len(w) > 1:
                        return "partial - multiple"
                    else:
                        return "partial - single"
    return "no match"
```

Usage:

```py
a = "1234", "tes", "1234 abc", "tes abc", "dfdfd"
b = "1234", "testing12", "test"

for s in a:
    print(s, "|", match_string(s, b))
```

Output:

```
1234 | exact - single
tes | partial - single
1234 abc | exact - multiple
tes abc | partial - multiple
dfdfd | no match
```

Comment: changed if j.startswith(i): so the partial matching only works when the string is the start of the matching word.